# pthread_join skipping first thread

Tags: multithreading, join, pthreads

So I have the following code, some of it left out so it's easier to understand.

```
for (unsigned int t = 0; t < NUM_THREADS; t++)
    {

        if (pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, thread_run, (void*) &threadData) != 0)
        {
            perror("pthread_create");
        }//end if
    }

    for (unsigned int z = 0; z < NUM_THREADS; z++)
    {
        if (pthread_join(threads[z], NULL) != 0)
        {
            perror("pthread_join");
        }
    }
```

My Problem is the join function, it is skipping the first thread I create, and continuing on.  The current solution I have is adding an extra thread and not making the first one do any work.

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO there is not pthreads problem; you are just creating `NUM_THREADS + 1` threads and join only first `NUM_THREADS` of them.

Comment: Opps; that's not suppose to be there, that is used in my solution to the problem, I will update the code now.

Comment: @Pieces So you say that the `pthread_join(threads[0])` returns without waiting for `threads[0]` and no errors are returned? This rather suggests it is already terminated when the join loop fires.

Comment: It doesn't because that data that needs to be written out does not exist.

Comment: @Pices Thread can kill itself anytime leaving NULL or just bad pointer. I'm just sure that the problem exists in the other parts of code than this creation and join loops.

Comment: @mbq, what are some common causes for this? Ty

Comment: @Pieces Mostly return in the thread function ;-) Fire debugger or add some debug-printfs to see what this first thread really does.